# To find diff between 2 vectors

Tags: r, match, set-difference

To find diff between 2 vectors - one of the answers mentioned was:

`x[is.na(match(x,y))]`

with `x <- c(1,2,3,4); y <- c(2,3,4`.

Can someone please explain this answer in detail ?

Comment: Here x and y are - 
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(2,3,4)

Answer (score 0):

Just break it down to steps,

```
match(x,y)           #If no match is found, it returns (by default) NA
#[1] NA  1  2  3

is.na(match(x,y))    #Thus, is.na will create a logical vector for NA values
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

x[is.na(match(x,y))]    #Using the above logical vector as index for x
#[1] 1
```